# How to protect (obfuscate/DRM) trained model weights in Tensorflow.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I am working on a React-based web app that uses Tensorflow.js to run an AI model in realtime on the client in the browser. I've trained this AI model from scratch and I'd like to protect it from being intercepted and used in other projects. Are there any protections available to do this (obfuscation, DRM, etc.)?

From a business perspective, I'd *only* like the model to work on my web app, nowhere else.

The discussions ([1](https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/7k6int/d_how_do_you_obfuscate_your_model_before_sending/)  [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45321123/tensorflow-model-protection-on-mobile) [3](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9501)) I've been able to find on this are more geared toward native apps, not web apps.

[Here](https://github.com/justadudewhohacks/face-api.js/tree/master/weights) is an example open source web app that uses Tensorflow.js. These weights are an example of what I would like to protect in my app.

Answer (score 5):

**Client-side code obfuscation will never fully prevent it. Use a server instead.**

#### Obfuscation

If your client-side application contains the model, then the user will be able to somehow extract it. You can make it harder for the user, but it will always be possible. Some techniques to make it harder are:

- **[Obfuscating](https://stackoverflow.com/q/194397/5627599) your code**: That way the user will not be able to read your code and comments easily. Depending on your build tools, this might already be done for you when you produce a "production ready" build.
- **Obfuscating the library and its public API**: Even if your code is obfuscated, the user might still be able to guess what is going on by seeing the public API calls of the library. Example: It would be rather easy to set a break point at the `model.predict` function and debug your code from there on. By also obfuscating libraries and their API, this will become harder.
- **Put "special checks" in your code**: You could also check if the page the code is running on is your page (e.g. if the domain matches), etc. You also want to obfuscate this code as well.

Even if your code is perfectly obfuscated and well protected, your client-side code still contains your model somewhere. With these methods it will always be possible to somehow extract your model.

#### Server-side approach

To make it impossible to get your model, you need a different approach. Only put your "dumb logic" on the client. Exclude the part of code that you want to protect. Instead you offer a API on your server that executes the "protected part" of your code.

This way, instead of running `model.predict` on the client-side, you would make an AJAX request to your backend (with the parameters) and then return the results. That way the user only sees the input and the output and cannot extract the model itself.

Keep in mind that this means a lot more work, as you not only have to write the code for your client-side application but also for your server-side application, including the API. Depending on how your application looks like (e.g.: does it have a login?), this might be a lot more code.

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can protect your model is to split the model into more than one blocks. Put some blocks at server side and some at client side. This method may also introduce a lot of engineering work, but once you do that you can trade off the computation loading and network latency between the server and client. Users can only get some model blocks which is useless without cooperating with server side blocks.