# Tensorflow.js - Security: Are the models Imported Secure?

Tags: javascript, node.js, obfuscation, tensorflow.js

I am new to tensorflow.js. We have a couple of tensorflow models in saved format. My question is if we convert those into tfs.js and load them in the browser, let's say in a web application secured with user-id and password. Can someone steal the model? Let's say a client of the web application logs in, tries out a prediction and then decides to copy the pre-trained model which our company has invested so much of time and money in developing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to protect (obfuscate/DRM) trained model weights in Tensorflow.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56919400/how-to-protect-obfuscate-drm-trained-model-weights-in-tensorflow-js)